# How do you stop a kubernetes namespace from terminating without deleting it?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes namespace in `phase: Terminating` (waiting on finalizers or something) and I want it to stop terminating, without deleting it.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Stop a kubernetes namespace from terminating by updating the finalizers associated with it.

The finalizers of a namespace determine the conditions that must be met before the namespace can be deleted. If a namespace is in a "Terminating" state, it means that there are still finalizers associated with it that need to be resolved. To stop the termination, you need to remove the finalizers from the namespace's resource definition.

You can do it by:

1. retrieving the current definition of the namespace:

```
kubectl get namespace <namespace-name> -o yaml > namespace.yaml
```

2. then in the definition file, look for the finalizers field and remove the items associated with it:

```
# vi/nano/emacs namespace.yaml # open with your favorite editor
# and replace:

apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: <namespace-name>
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes
```

save it.

3. and then update the namespace definition with the edited file:

```
kubectl replace -f namespace.yaml
```

After that, the namespace should no longer be in a "Terminating" state and will remain intact.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. Can you give more detail in step 2?